# select matched session from mysql to a table

Tags: php, mysql, session, post

Here's some code I use to send submit form information to my database...

```
<?php

   $Name = $_SESSION['Name'];  
   $Age = $_SESSION['Age'];  
   $Place = $_SESSION['Place']; 


  /*will work */
    if ($mysqli->query("INSERT into demo (Name, Age, Place) VALUES ('$Name', '$Age', '$Place')"));  

       $mysqli->close(); 

    ?>
```

Ok, so now on my search page I need to recover/select this information below from my database and into a table:

```
    $Name = $_SESSION['Name'];  
   $Age = $_SESSION['Age'];  
   $Place = $_SESSION['Place'];
```

Please help me how to do this:) 
Thank you.

Comment: `session_start();` loaded? If it isn't do, plus make sure your form elements are indeed named if you are using a form. Those session variables aren't going to do anything (nor populate on their own) until something is assigned to them. All you're doing now is assigning dead variables to them.

Comment: Use a select statement:
`SELECT Name, Age, Place from demo`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29

Comment: Just like your INSERT query, write a SELECT query to get that data

Comment: Here: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and you'll see what I mean, plus check for errors in SQL, both of which you are **not** doing. As for doing the rest, this is "work", not "help". Hanky said it, do a `SELECT` instead.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `<?php session_start(); ?>` on the top of every page where you'd like to use the `$_SESSION[]` variables.